# Vector Graphics Library supporting animation C#/Java/Python

Tags: animation, graphics, vector

Is there any vector graphics library (free or commercial) with available documentation preferably in C#, Java, Python or other managed languages, which supports animation? I want to develop an application where I can create vector graphics or at least import vector graphics files created in another application. I want to be able to animate vector graphics programmatically, e.g., translate, fade in/out, change color, resize, morph, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx)?

Most of the requirements that you describe are very basic and supported by WPF. The only extra you'll need is some logic that is able to import the vector formats you need.

Are you sure you stated all the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

There is [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) -- free (GPL) cross-platform plotting library. It have interface to Python (can use numpy arrays).

In principle, interfaces to C# and Java can be easily created using SWIG, but I don't test it. If somebody interested on it then I can quickly make these interfaces and check with yours help.